# Ms Access SQL automitacally picking a field based on the 1st choice

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]
in this table Customer is actually storing `CUSID` (i have pleased the caption customer and made it display the name to which the `CUSID` corresponds to)
now in the `CUSnum` field i want it to automatically pic the number `CUSID` of which was entered into the previous field (if he customer doesnt exist it should all to add the number of unregistered customer)

i came up with the following SQL

```
SELECT [Customer].[CUSContact] 
FROM Customer 
WHERE [Sale].[CUSID] = [Customer].[CUSID];
```

but for some reason it is not automatically catching the `CUSID` from the sale table but asking for it to be manually inputted ! please help !

Comment: You are using a lookup to replace `CUSID` with the customer's name? i.e. `Azaad Fazal Khan` would really be `123`? And you want that number, `123`, to show up un `the CUSnum` column?

Comment: @Brad yes i used lookup wizard to achieve replacing of CUSID with CUSName it is storing CUSID while displaying otherwise and i want another field "CUSContact" to be automatically be picked from customer table where primery key (cusid) = the one stored in Customer

Comment: It also sounds like you are trying to execute more logic that you should in a table. This seems like ti should the located in a form.

Comment: i believe you are right thanks any way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do here is understand how to use [Relationships](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx) in a Microsoft Access environment.  This is a perfect example of using Referrential Integrity to perform a Cascading Update.  I would highly suggest reading the linked article before you try to try to bandaid a hack the way you've described above.